# Looking for LaTeX templates.

Tags: templates, document-classes

where can I find a 'professional' document templates in LaTeX. I need two different one to the other user documentation and second for developer documentation. I know that I can safely create it myself, but I have no idea of ​​the appearance of these documents.

Comment: A LaTeX user would typically pick a document class best suited for a task and add packages. Are you looking for class and package recommendations or something else entirely?

Answer (score 5):

[CTAN](http://ctan.org/) is the Comprehensive TeX Archive Network.  You might try looking at some of the [alternative document classes](http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/bytopic.html#classes) there.